How is the thread leader selected when using `std::sync::Barrier`?
I'm learning std::sync::Barrier in Rust.
According to the documentation of the wait() method:

pub fn wait(&self) -> BarrierWaitResult
(snip)
Barriers are re-usable after all threads have rendezvoused once, and can be used continuously.
A single (arbitrary) thread will receive a BarrierWaitResult that returns true from BarrierWaitResult::is_leader() when returning from this function, and all other threads will receive a result that will return false from BarrierWaitResult::is_leader().

I have two questions:

How is the leader selected?

If we reuse a barrier, is the leader selected in the first use always selected as the leader also in the second use? (As far as I tested, this is true.) Edit: the answer is no (playground).



What answer are you looking for beyond what's been documented - it's selected arbitrarily. If you want or need the leader to have some special property, it's up to you to establish that after selection. If you're asking for some specific purpose, please outline what that purpose is.

@Damien_The_Unbeliever The purpose of this question is purely how it works under the hood. This is not an XY problem indeed. I started reading the source code now...

From the implementation of wait():
pub fn wait(&self) -> BarrierWaitResult {
    let mut lock = self.lock.lock().unwrap();
    let local_gen = lock.generation_id;
    lock.count += 1;
    if lock.count < self.num_threads {
        let _guard =
            self.cvar.wait_while(lock, |state| local_gen == state.generation_id).unwrap();
        BarrierWaitResult(false)
    } else {
        lock.count = 0;
        lock.generation_id = lock.generation_id.wrapping_add(1);
        self.cvar.notify_all();
        BarrierWaitResult(true)
    }
}

it appears that it keeps a count of all threads. when a given thread rendezvouses, if it is the last thread, it will become the leader (BarrierWaitResult(true)), otherwise it will become not be the leader (BarrierWaitResult(false)).

"Last thread that wait() called from" might be a better fit, that means leader will still be an arbitrary thread.

This also answers the strike-through-ed question in the OP; the leader generally changes every time we reuse a barrier.
